# Data truncation with auto_now and auto_now_save on Windwos

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

After I upgraded to Django 1.9.1, I started getting this error when I try to post a new object (using Django REST Framework):

```
Data truncated for column 'added_on' at row 1
```

The field 'added_on' is defined as:

```
added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I enabled SQL logging to see the generated SQL query, I found this query:

```
(0.218) INSERT INTO `hadiths_book` (`title`, `brief_desc`, `pub_year`, `added_on`, `updated_on`, `added_by`, `updated_by`) VALUES ('12345678', '', NULL, '2016-01-30 10:27:08.837000+00:00', '2016-01-30 10:27:08.837000+00:00', NULL, NULL); args=[u'12345678', u'', None, u'2016-01-30 10:27:08.837000+00:00', u'2016-01-30 10:27:08.837000+00:00', None, None]
```

which explains why the problem is happening. **This happens only on Windows**. On Ubuntu, I get this SQL query:

```
(0.054) INSERT INTO `hadiths_book` (`title`, `brief_desc`, `pub_year`, `added_on`, `updated_on`, `added_by`, `updated_by`) VALUES ('1234567', '', NULL, '2016-01-30 10:20:30', '2016-01-30 10:20:30', NULL, NULL); args=[u'1234567', u'', None, u'2016-01-30 10:20:30', u'2016-01-30 10:20:30', None, None]
```

Notice the datetime fields on Windows contains milliseconds and timezone information while on Ubuntu it doesn't.

Any reason for this difference on the two operation systems? Notice that I am using the same version of Django and Django REST Framework on both systems.

**UPDATE:** I am hitting the same database server, which is a MySQL server. On both servers I am using the latest Django (1.9.1) and Django REST Framework (3.3.2). The only difference I can think of is the driver.

Comment: It might be a difference in the database backends between windows and linux. Are you using sqlite?

Comment: It is the same exact database server actually. It is a MySQL server.

Comment: Could it be a different [MySQL DB API Driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) ?

Comment: Since postgres/linux is more common in production django than mysql/windows, this could be a bug that not have been discovered by beta testers. If this bug breaks anything, the simplest fix might be to migrate to postgres.

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of this bug, you should add the `mysql` tag to the question. The error `Data truncated for column 'added_on' at row 1` comes from mysql, not from django-rest-framework.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, but I don't know PostGre to migrate to it. And yes, it could be driver problem, as the driver on Windows is different than the one in Ubuntu.